# In a shell, how to put together lines that have common strings on other lines

Tags: list, shell, awk

I have a file like this and I need to bring together the strings that are common and have links, an example to be more understandable :

- aaa bbb ccc
- bbb ccc ddd
- ccc
- ddd
- eee ggg
- fff aaa
- ggg

and I would like to get this stdout :

- aaa bbb ccc ddd fff
- eee ggg

I don’t know how I could do that.
sorry for my english, i'm learning

Comment: It's not clear from the example what makes the string common?  And what have you found?

Answer (score 1):

well, you could iterate through the lines, split them into lists (using split.()), use a conditional to detect whether the lists of two strings overlap the way that would make you consider them similar, then modify the lists and join them to produce the combined (it seems?) strings you'd like to see.

Cannot help with the actual code, because I am not sure what these lines have in common exactly.